# Проверить, является ли значение объекта значением по умолчанию. C#

Tags: c#, .net, объекты, рефлексия

**Update: В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713230/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E) находятся реализации функции, представленные под этим вопросом. Самая быстрая реализация V7**

Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает объект и возвращает имеет ли объект значение по умолчанию или нет.

```
public bool IsDefault(object o)
{
    return ...
}
```

Сейчас единственное что я придумал, это узнавать имя типа и через switch проверять имеет ли объект значение по умолчанию для типа. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
string typeName = o.GetType().Name;
switch (typeName)
{
    case "Int32":
        if(Convert.ToInt32(o) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    case "String":
        if (o == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(o)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: А использовать дженерики нельзя? Именно object? С дженериками такую штуку сделать можно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895761/test-for-equality-to-the-default-value

Comment: @iluxa1810 что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я думаю тут проще через Generic, только нужно через reflection вызвать Generic. Generic - возможность "подставить тип". А подставить его можно в `default(T)`.

Comment: Если все таки использовать дженерика нельзя, то можно ручками свичи дописать. Я думаю, что вам максимум нужно 4 штуки, так как все цифры имеют 0 по умолчанию, строки пусто или null, объекты null, еще есть nullable типы.

Comment: хм, вы `string` проверяете не просто на значение по умолчанию, но и на пустую строку, которая не есть значение по умолчанию

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Думаю самый лучший вариант вот:

```
 bool isDefault<T>(T o) { return (o==null)?true: // считаем что null default
  o.GetType().IsValueType && !typeof(T).IsGenericType ? 
    o.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType())): // default типа который внутри nullable
    o.Equals(default(T)); // настоящий default
}
```

Оказывается если идёт cast в object - то обьект немного "коробится". При этом может терятся информация о template (спорный вопрос с Nullable). Для "простых" типов я это учёл в втором условии.

Но самый "правильный" вот

```
    bool isDefault<T>(T o) { return (o==null)?(default(T)==null):o.Equals(default(T));
```

при этом `isDefault((object)0)` этот вариант даст `false`, т.к. `defalut(object) != 0` что может не понравится разработчику, этот случй хороший только при использовании template. В зависимости от того работаете вы с template типом или кастите всё к object вам подходит тот или иной способ. Если вы хотите что б IsDefault((int?)0) было true - прийдётся чуть упростить (убрать IsGenericType). Случай default(T)==null бывает, но очень врядли `default(T)!=null` и `o == null` будет одновременно, поэтому вместо `default(T)!=null` можно писать `true`

Остальные оставлю для истории...

1. Через рефлексию (тут идёт Cast в object поэтому теряются некоторые значения, например `IsDefault((int?)0)` даст true

   ```
   class YourClass {

     public static T getDefault<T>() {
            return default(T);
          }

   public bool IsDefault(object o){
     if (o == null) return true; // условно
     object cmp = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("getDefault")
     .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]{   o.GetType() } ).Invoke(null,null);
     // теперь cmp содержит "дефолтное" значение
     bool equal = o.Equals(cmp); // дефолтное значение может быть null
    return equal;
    }
   ```

Для этого нужно соединить два вопроса вот это
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895761/test-for-equality-to-the-default-value
соединить с вот этим
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204326/calling-generic-method-using-reflection-in-net

2. Если же вам тип заранее известен, то можно просто использовать generic без reflection так

   ```
   bool isObjDefault<T>(object o) { return o.Equals(default(T)); }
   ```

   тут тоже теряется информация - `IsDefault((int?)0)` даст true,

поэтому лучше даже так (оказывается так не нужно указывать тип, и обьект не конвертируется в object, из-за конвертации может теряется тип)

```
    bool isDefault<T>(T o) { return (o==null)?true:o.Equals(default(T)); }
```

3. Ну а если у вас два-три типа можно так (без generic, просто сравнение типа):

   ```
   if (o is int) return o.Equals(default(int));
   if (o is string) return o.Equals(default(string));
   ```
4. Ещё необычный "короткий" вариант (с классами сработало с числами и строками тоже, правда этот вариант более затратный по ресурсам, зато в одну строчку)

   ```
   public bool IsDefault(object o) {
     return (o==null)?true:o.GetType().Assembly.CreateInstance(o.GetType().FullName).Equals(o);
     }
   ```

   но этот метод создаёт пустую іnstance если нету default значения, поэтому подходит в отдельных случаях.

P.S. 1. Для классов default значение как правило null (случай когда не null в студию - не нашёл такого) в том числе и generic.  Для valuetype и для struct существуют default значения.

2. Очень часто в программах можно увидеть использования object для всех типов. При конветации в object могут терятся данные, например от Nullable<> остаётся либо исходный null без типа, либо int, а настоящий тип теряется. Поэтому можно записать две функции f1(x) != f2(x)  там где есть конвертация будет не то значение.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли преимущество у вашего метода перед такой функцией public static bool IsDefault<T>(T o)
        {
            return object.Equals(o, default(T));
        } ? Просто если они есть для меня они не очевидны.

Comment: Преимущество - простота. Только нужно кроме аргумента подставлять тип. Т.е. `isObjDefault<int>(1)` или так `isObjDefault<string>("")`

Comment: @nick_n_a: А зачем в (2) явно указывать тип? Скомпилируется по идее и без него.

Comment: @VladD, тип надо указывать, т. к. работать будет не правильно, например: `isObjDefault(0)` вернет `True`, а `isObjDefault((object)0)` вернет `False`

Comment: @VladD, а вот `isObjDefault<int>((object)0)` вернет `True`

Comment: Хм, кстати вообще не компилируется, т.к. тип параметра `object` и однозначно `T` компилятор никак не определит, поэтому только явное указание типа. Параметр сделать `T o` тоже нельзя, получается

Comment: Что интересно, студия еще этот `default` неправильно воспринимает - предлагает удалить `(T)`, но после удаления функция перестает правильно работать

Comment: Там где надо `T o` я теперь делаю так `T o = default(T);`  а раньше когда не знал как `T o = (T)typeof(T).GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(null);`

Comment: @Андрей: Ах да, боксированные объекты! Точно.

Comment: Все методы, кроме второго, неправильно работают на переменной `int? x = 0`.

Comment: @VladD я поправил код - исправил этот глюк.

Comment: @nick_n_a подскажите пожалуйста, почему вы решили, что вариант  bool isDefault<T>(T o) { return (o==null)?true:o.Equals(default(T));} является лучшим решением? Я просто уже мало что понимаю в обсуждениях в комментариях. Не обладаю достаточными знаниями

Comment: @nick_n_a: Финальный вариант всё ещё не справляется с `(int?)0`.

Comment: @Vlad поправил. IsGenericType  и IsValueType таки могут быть одновременно.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Теперь не проходит `(object)0`.

Comment: @VladD коварный box. Поменял

Comment: @nick_n_a: Последний вариант взломать не смог :)

Answer (score 10):

Мы не имеем права «терять» настоящий тип объекта, иначе будет невозможно отличить `int?` от `int`. Поэтому придётся делать вот такой вариант:

```
bool IsDefault<T>(T o)
{
    if (o == null) // => ссылочный тип или nullable
        return true;
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) // nullable, не null
        return false;
    var type = o.GetType();
    if (type.IsClass)
        return false;
    else           // => тип-значение, есть конструктор по умолчанию
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(o);
}
```

Проверка:

```
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault(default(string))); // true
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault(string.Empty));    // false
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault(default(int)));    // true
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault(1));               // false
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault(default(int?)));   // true
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault((int?)0));         // false
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault((object)0));       // true
Console.WriteLine(IsDefault((object)1));       // false
```

На объект `(object)(int?)0` метод выдаст `true`, т. к. переданный объект — упакованный `int`, а не упакованный `int?` (его не бывает в природе).

Comment: А дефолтным значением generic стоит считать дефолтное значение generic-a или дефолтное значение обвётки ( int?  = Nullable<int> )? Т.е. default(int?) = null, но  default(int)=0, т.е. тут уже зависит от постановки задачи...

Comment: @nick_n_a, каково дефолтное значение `List<int>`? не 0 же...

Comment: @nick_n_a: Я беру дефолтное значение настоящего типа (`GetType()`). Для случая классов это null, разницы нет. Для случая Value Type производных типов нет, и разницы тоже. Единственная разница — для Nullable, но я его отсеиваю «вручную».

Comment: Вот, кстати, `Nullable` странно себя ведут, неочевидным образом, при передаче в параметре они меняют тип?

Comment: о_О, никогда не задумывался над этим, но `new Nullable<int>() == null` и у него даже `.GetType()` вызвать нельзя

Comment: @Андрей: Они меняют тип при упаковке. При передаче тип остаётся правильным, но для `GetType` нужно упаковать в `object`.

Comment: @Андрей: Это тоже эффект упаковки, т. к. вызывается `operator == (object, object)`. Реально это не `null`, т. к. это структура.

Comment: А чем вам  bool isDefault<T>(T o) { return o.Equals(default(T)); } не нравится?

Comment: @nick_n_a: Тем, что нужно знать точный тип. Если у меня `int`, упакованный в `object`, откуда я узнаю его настоящий тип? Я действовал согласно [этому комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713106/713118#comment1068478_713118)

Answer (score 4):

Значение по умолчанию для типа можно получить так:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type target)
{
    Expression<Func<object>> e = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Default(target), typeof(object)));

    return e.Compile()();
}
```

Использование:

```
public bool IsDefault(object o)
{
    if(o == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));

    return o.Equals(GetDefaultValue(o.GetType()));
}
```

Comment: `o.Equals(GetDefaultValue(o.GetType()))` это можно же переписать просто как `o.Equals(default(o.GetType()))` и вспомогательная ф-я не нужна

Comment: @Андрей и ловите ошибку компиляции type expected. Поэтому и создаётся функция, при чём ещё и template.

Comment: @nick_n_a, хм, согласен, `default()` - это не ф-я, а ключевое слово языка

Comment: @nick_n_a, хотя с C# 7.1 доступно же сравнение типа: `1 == default` или `1 is default`, но что интересно, `(0 == default)` возвращает `True`, `(object)0 == default` вообще использовать нельзя, а `(object)0 is default` возвращает `False`...

Answer (score 3):

На днях вышло обновление языка c# до версии 7.1 и теперь вы можете писать так:

```
return (o is default);
```

**UPD**
Не будет работать, так как `o` типа `object`, а `default(object) == null`

Comment: Нет! `default` заменится во время компиляции! И всегда будет равен `(object)null`!

Comment: Не верный ответ - тоже ответ заслуживающий внимания (он показывает как не надо делать).

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант, который кажется мне наиболее быстрым. Воспользуемся трюком [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775837/276994):

```
class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }

static bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class
{
    if (o == null)
        return true;
    if (!(o is ValueType)) // не упакованная ли это структура?
        return false;      // нет - выходим
    return Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o); // медленный путь
}
static bool IsDefault<T>(T? o) where T : struct =>
    o == null;
static bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct =>
   default(T).Equals(o); // default(T) не требует рефлексии
```

Comment: спасибо большое за проделанную вами работу. Но может вас не затруднит проверить шестой вариант реализации функции вместе с большим количеством перегрузок? Мне кажется, что когда для каждого стандартного типа C# есть одна проверка на значение по умолчанию, сравнение должно работать еще быстрее, чем при использовании generic функции.

Comment: @mirypoko: Хорошо, я проверю позже. Я думаю, что «индивидуальные» варианты для структуры и `Nullable` могут быть немного быстрее за счёт прямого сравнения, не через виртуальную функцию `Equals`. Но JITter может и заинлайнить Equals (ведь он знает точный тип), так что есть шанс, что быстрее не будет.

Comment: @mirypoko: Я оттестировал вариант V6 с добавленными «индивидуальными» реализациями из V5. Да, получается скорее. Сейчас обновлю бенчмарки.