# Сравнение алгоритмов проверки переменной на значение по умолчанию

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

**Update: Самым быстрым оказался алгоритм V7**

Продолжение предыдущего [вопроса.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713106/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-c)

Есть несколько вариантов реализации функции для проверки переменной на значение по умолчанию. Из комментариев к предыдущему вопросу я понял лишь то, что мне еще очень много предстоит выучить в C#. Помогите пожалуйста найти самый **производительный и надежный** вариант реализации функции.

В качестве параметра функции может быть все что угодно, включая класс, структуру, типы на подобие int? и так далее.

Некоторые варианты реализации функции:

**V1:**

```
bool IsDefault<T>(T o)
{
    if (o == null) // => ссылочный тип или nullable
        return true;
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) // nullable, не null
        return false;
    var type = o.GetType();
    //для .net core type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass
    if (type.IsClass) 
        return false;
    else       // => тип-значение, есть конструктор по умолчанию
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(o);
}
```

**V3 (улучшенный)**

```
bool isDefault<T>(T o) 
{ 
    return (o==null)?true: // считаем что null default
      o.GetType().IsValueType && !typeof(T).IsGenericType ? 
      o.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType())): // default типа который внутри nullable
      o.Equals(default(T)); // настоящий default
}
```

**V5 смешать V1 и большое кол-во перегрузок под все типы:**

```
public class DefaultChecker
{
    bool IsDefault(byte value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(byte? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(sbyte value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(sbyte? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(int value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(int? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(uint value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(uint? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(short value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(short? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(ushort value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(ushort? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(long value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(long? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(ulong value) => value == 0;
    bool IsDefault(ulong? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(float value) => value == 0.0F;
    bool IsDefault(float? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(double value) => value == 0.0D;
    bool IsDefault(double? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(char value) => value == '\0';
    bool IsDefault(char? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(bool value) => !value;
    bool IsDefault(bool? value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(string value) => value == null;
    bool IsDefault(decimal value) => value == 0.0M;
    bool IsDefault(decimal? value) => value == null;

    public bool IsDefault<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null) // => ссылочный тип или nullable
            return true;
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) // nullable, не null
            return false;
        var type = value.GetType();
        //для .net core type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass
        if (type.IsClass)
            return false;
        else       // => тип-значение, есть конструктор по умолчанию
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(value);
    }
}
```

**V6:**

```
class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }

static bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class
{
    if (o == null)
        return true;
    if (!(o is ValueType)) // не упакованная ли это структура?
        return false;      // нет - выходим
    return Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o); // медленный путь
}

static bool IsDefault<T>(T? o) where T : struct =>
    o == null;

static bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct =>
   default(T).Equals(o); // default(T) не требует рефлексии
```

**V7 смешать V6 и большое кол-во перегрузок под все типы:**

```
bool IsDefault(byte value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(byte? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(sbyte value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(sbyte? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(int value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(int? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(uint value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(uint? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(short value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(short? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(ushort value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(ushort? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(long value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(long? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(ulong value) => value == 0;
bool IsDefault(ulong? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(float value) => value == 0.0F;
bool IsDefault(float? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(double value) => value == 0.0D;
bool IsDefault(double? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(char value) => value == '\0';
bool IsDefault(char? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(bool value) => !value;
bool IsDefault(bool? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(string value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault(decimal value) => value == 0.0M;
bool IsDefault(decimal? value) => value == null;
bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class
{
    if (o == null)
        return true;
    if (!(o is ValueType))
        return false;
    return Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o);
}
bool IsDefault<T>(T? o) where T : struct =>
    o == null;
bool IsDefault<T>(T o, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct =>
    default(T).Equals(o);
```

**---Реализации, которые не проходят тест---**

**V2:**

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type target)
{
    Expression<Func<object>> e = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Default(target), typeof(object)));
    return e.Compile()();
}

public bool IsDefault(object o)
{
    if(o == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));

    return o.Equals(GetDefaultValue(o.GetType()));
}
```

**V3:**

```
bool isDefault<T>(T o)
{ 
    return (o==null)?true:
        o.GetType().IsValueType ?  
        Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o) : 
        o.Equals(default(T)); 
}
```

**V4:**

```
//isDefault((object)0) этот вариант даст false
bool isDefault<T>(T o) 
{ 
    return (o==null)?(default(T)==null):o.Equals(default(T)); 
}
```

Comment: А не пробуете использовать реализацию интерфейса IEquatable<T> с изменением Equals и GetHashCode? По хешам может получиться быстрее. Правда не забываем про коллизию...

Возможно переопределить просто GetHashCode и использовать Hash для сравнения объектов

Comment: И раз уж на то пошло, возможно будет полезно вывезти все это дело на Github(вместе с тестами)

Comment: Выкатил обновление теста V6, он стал ещё быстрее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала, нужно составить юнит-тесты на желаемую функцию. Например, такие:

```
Debug.Assert(IsDefault(default(string)));
Debug.Assert(IsDefault((object)default(string)));
Debug.Assert(!IsDefault(string.Empty));
Debug.Assert(!IsDefault((object)string.Empty));
Debug.Assert(IsDefault(default(int)));
Debug.Assert(!IsDefault(1));
Debug.Assert(IsDefault(default(int?)));
Debug.Assert(!IsDefault((int?)0));
Debug.Assert(IsDefault((object)0));
Debug.Assert(!IsDefault((object)1));
```

Пробуем различные имплементации:

- V1 проходит.
- V2 бросает `ArgumentNullException` вместо того, чтобы вернуть `false`, на `Debug.Assert(IsDefault(default(string)));`.
- V3 <s>не проходит `Debug.Assert(!IsDefault((int?)0));`</s> проходит.
- V4 не проходит `Debug.Assert(IsDefault((object)0))`.
- V5 проходит.
- V6 проходит.
- V7 проходит.

---

Окей, на текущий момент тесты проходят V1, V3, V5, V6 и V7. Тестировалось при помощи [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), результаты ниже. Вот результаты:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.9, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 2 (10.0.15063)
Processor=Intel Core i7-6700 CPU 3.40GHz (Skylake), ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=3328123 Hz, Resolution=300.4697 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2102.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2102.0


 Method |       Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
------- |-----------:|---------:|---------:|
 TestV1 | 1,793.9 ns | 4.960 ns | 4.639 ns |
 TestV3 | 1,260.1 ns | 6.523 ns | 5.782 ns |
 TestV5 | 1,195.5 ns | 9.269 ns | 7.740 ns |
 TestV6 |   481.8 ns | 2.526 ns | 2.363 ns |
 TestV7 |   445.3 ns | 1.847 ns | 1.728 ns |
```

Обратите внимание, что код проверки пробегает в худшем случае за менее двух, а в лучшем — за половину микросекунды (то есть, одной миллионной части секунды). Поэтому искать выигрыш в любой из реализаций нет особенного смысла: все реализации пробегают очень быстро. Единственный случай, при котором имеет смысл задуматься об оптимизации — это если такая вот операция вызывается десятки тысяч раз. (Но в этом случае, возможно, имеет смысл пересмотреть дизайн программы.)

Если кому интересно, вот код сравнения (длинный и скучный):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Т
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>();
        }
    }

    public class Benchmarks
    {
        bool IsDefaultV1<T>(T o)
        {
            if (o == null) // => ссылочный тип или nullable
                return true;
            if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) // nullable, не null
                return false;
            var type = o.GetType();
            if (type.IsClass)
                return false;
            else       // => тип-значение, есть конструктор по умолчанию
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(o);
        }

        bool IsDefaultV3<T>(T o)
        {
            return (o == null) ? true : // считаем что null default
              o.GetType().IsValueType && !typeof(T).IsGenericType ?
              o.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType())) : // default типа который внутри nullable
              o.Equals(default(T)); // настоящий default
        }

        public bool IsDefaultV5(byte value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(byte? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(sbyte value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(sbyte? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(int value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(int? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(uint value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(uint? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(short value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(short? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(ushort value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(ushort? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(long value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(long? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(ulong value) => value == 0;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(ulong? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(float value) => value == 0.0F;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(float? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(double value) => value == 0.0D;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(double? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(char value) => value == '\0';
        public bool IsDefaultV5(char? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(bool value) => !value;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(bool? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(string value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(decimal value) => value == 0.0M;
        public bool IsDefaultV5(decimal? value) => value == null;
        public bool IsDefaultV5<T>(T value)
        {
            if (value == null) // => ссылочный тип или nullable
                return true;
            if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) // nullable, не null
                return false;
            var type = value.GetType();
            //для .net core type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass
            if (type.IsClass)
                return false;
            else       // => тип-значение, есть конструктор по умолчанию
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type).Equals(value);
        }

        class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
        class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }

        static bool IsDefaultV6<T>(T o, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class
        {
            if (o == null)
                return true;
            if (!(o is ValueType))
                return false;
            return Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o);
        }
        static bool IsDefaultV6<T>(T? o) where T : struct =>
            o == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV6<T>(T o, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct =>
            default(T).Equals(o);

        static bool IsDefaultV7(byte value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(byte? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(sbyte value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(sbyte? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(int value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(int? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(uint value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(uint? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(short value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(short? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(ushort value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(ushort? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(long value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(long? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(ulong value) => value == 0;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(ulong? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(float value) => value == 0.0F;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(float? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(double value) => value == 0.0D;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(double? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(char value) => value == '\0';
        static bool IsDefaultV7(char? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(bool value) => !value;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(bool? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(string value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(decimal value) => value == 0.0M;
        static bool IsDefaultV7(decimal? value) => value == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7<T>(T o, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class
        {
            if (o == null)
                return true;
            if (!(o is ValueType))
                return false;
            return Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType()).Equals(o);
        }
        static bool IsDefaultV7<T>(T? o) where T : struct =>
            o == null;
        static bool IsDefaultV7<T>(T o, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct =>
            default(T).Equals(o);

        struct Test<T>
        {
            int x;
            public Test(int x) { this.x = x; }
        }

        List<object> l1 = default;
        List<object> l2 = new List<object>();
        string s1 = default;
        string s2 = string.Empty;
        int i1 = default;
        int i2 = 1;
        int? ni1 = default;
        int? ni2 = 0;
        object bi1 = 0;
        object bi2 = 1;
        Test<int> t1 = default;
        Test<int> t2 = new Test<int>(1);
        object tb1 = default(Test<int>);
        object tb2 = new Test<int>(1);
        ValueType tc1 = default(Test<int>);
        ValueType tc2 = new Test<int>(1);

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestV1()
        {
            return
                (IsDefaultV1(l1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(l2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(s1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(s2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(i1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(i2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(ni1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(ni2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(bi1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(bi2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(t1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(t2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(tb1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(tb2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV1(tc1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV1(tc2) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestV3()
        {
            return
                (IsDefaultV3(l1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(l2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(s1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(s2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(i1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(i2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(ni1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(ni2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(bi1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(bi2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(t1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(t2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(tb1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(tb2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV3(tc1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV3(tc2) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestV5()
        {
            return
                (IsDefaultV5(l1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(l2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(s1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(s2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(i1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(i2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(ni1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(ni2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(bi1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(bi2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(t1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(t2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(tb1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(tb2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV5(tc1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV5(tc2) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestV6()
        {
            return
                (IsDefaultV6(l1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(l2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(s1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(s2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(i1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(i2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(ni1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(ni2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(bi1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(bi2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(t1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(t2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(tb1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(tb2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV6(tc1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV6(tc2) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestV7()
        {
            return
                (IsDefaultV7(l1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(l2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(s1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(s2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(i1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(i2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(ni1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(ni2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(bi1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(bi2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(t1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(t2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(tb1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(tb2) ? 1 : 0) +
                (IsDefaultV7(tc1) ? 1 : 0) +
                (!IsDefaultV7(tc2) ? 1 : 0);
        }

        public void CheckCorrectness()
        {
            var testMethods =
                this.GetType()
                    .GetMethods()
                    .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("TestV"))
                    .Select(m => (name: m.Name, func: (Func<int>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), this)))
                    .ToList();
            foreach ((var name, var func) in testMethods)
            {
                Console.Write($"Testing {name}... ");
                var ok = func() == 16;
                Console.WriteLine(ok ? "success" : "FAILED");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На данный момент ваши тесты проходят V1, V3 (улучшенный) и V5.