# .Net freamwork теряет тип nullable и приводит его к основному типу?

Tags: c#, .net

При попытке получить тип переменной которая была `Nullable`, посредством вызова `GetType`, я получаю основной тип и невозможно понять какой тип был изначально `Nullable` или нет:

```
using System;

namespace NullableQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Nullable<int> val = 123;

            Console.WriteLine(val.GetType().ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Вышеприведенный код выведет на консоль `System.Int32`, хотя, по логике вещей, он должен вывести нам то что это `System.Nullable[System.Int32]`!
Как думаете это баг и пора писать в Microsoft?

**UPDATE**
Последовав совету

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type

я попытался определить тип их способом

```
using System;

namespace NullableQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Nullable<int> val = 123;

            Type type = val.GetType();

            Console.Write("val is nullable: ");
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<Int32>))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(true);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(false);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(val.GetType().ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Но данный код видимо работает не корректно либо я что то не верно понял. Я получаю false.

Comment: Microsoft уже догадывается об этом: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type

Comment: *...Remember that this code always returns false if the Type object was returned from a call to GetType, as explained earlier in this topic.*

Comment: Посмотрите еще это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713161/218063

Comment: Получить настоящий тип можно так: `Type GetOriginalType<T>(T o) => typeof(T); int? x = 10; Console.WriteLine(GetOriginalType(x));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это не баг, это так задумано. Дело в том что `GetType()` - это метод не `System.Nullable`, а `System.Object`, а значит вызвать его можно только предварительно упаковав (box) значение.

Но особенность `System.Nullable` заключается в том, что при упаковке он всегда автоматически приводится к своему типу-параметру:

```
int? x = 123;
object y = x; // y - упакованный int
```

При распаковке же случается обратное преобразование:

```
object y = 123; // y - упакованный int
int? x = (int?)y; // x == 123
```

Comment: `Nullable` упаковывать смысла нет, т.к. `object` может и так иметь значение `null`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это понятно, но "нет смысла" еще не означает автоматически что этого не делается.

Comment: Я просто предположил мотивацию такого решения разработчиками. Только и всего :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, так Nullable и не объект, это ж структура, или я не совсем понял что имелось ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy, структура. А что не так? В ней имеется отдельное поле для хранения Value и флага что у нас Null. Когда мы боксим в object - флаг хранить не нужно, ибо null и так можно в object поместить